# Correct path of a image in WP folder

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my root folder there is a CSS folder:

```
CSS/style.css
```

On the above path I have written this code →

```
.loading.active { background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}.
```

I also tried this version:

```
url(img/loading.gif)
```

Can someone help me to write the correct path?

[image]

Comment: Try `url(./img/loading.gif)`

Comment: Tried not working.

Comment: what about `url(../img/loading.gif)`

Comment: Try clearing cache and then check.

Comment: Give me 10-15 minutes. Lost connection to serverr. I will update you soon. Thanks!